How to use the latest Clang compiler on GitHub macOS runner?
I'm trying to compile a rust project on GitHub actions on a macOS runner. At somepoint it tries to compile the llama-cpp-sys crate. It however fails with the following message:
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'

I had this issue in my local machine and I solved it by updating Xcode and my local environment now has clang 15.0.0. and everything compiles just fine.
Reading through some online issues I found out that the macOS runners actually have newer version of clang installed and one can access it via:
$(brew --prefix llvm@15)/bin/clang

I've tried to create a symbolic link to this version to allow the rust compilation to pass but to no success:
Run ln -s $(brew --prefix llvm@15)/bin/clang /usr/local/bin/clang

Run clang --version
Homebrew clang version 15.0.7
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin

I still get the same error. Any ideas what could I do to use the latest clang on the Rust compilation?

I suspect that the mac runner could be running in x86_64. Maybe try to run on ARM64 architecture i.e. arch -arm64e /usr/bin/clang --version

I started printing out variables names and other configuration artifacts and as it turns out the GitHub runners are mislabeled. I was running my script in a macos-latest runner. And according to the documentation this is supposed to be a m1 machine, it is however a intel x86_64 machine. After changing the runner to a macos-14 tag then the default clang version was correct and finally everything was compiling.
